# how to get the last entry of previous month from db in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a table `attendace` that have a attendance of different  date.Now i want to get the attendance for last entry of previous month.I used this:

```
$attt = Attendance::find()
    ->select('daytime')
    ->orderBy(['daytime' => SORT_DESC])
    ->one();
```

to get the last entry of previous month but it does not give me last entry of previous month.My table is [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting

```
$yourMonth = date('m') -1;
$attt = Attendance::find()->select('daytime')
->where(" MONTH( my_date_field) = $yourMonth ")
->orderBy(['daytime'=>SORT_DESC])->one();
```

Comment: but i do not have set fixed value .i want that as month change it take the last entry of previous month.i tried using above code and get error            `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION yii_attendance.DATEPART does not exist
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `daytime` FROM `attendance` WHERE DATEPART(month, my_date_field) = 8 ORDER BY `daytime` DESC`

Comment: error :`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'my_date_field) = 8 ORDER BY daytime DESC at line 1
The SQL being executed was: SELECT  daytime FROM  attendance WHERE MONTH( my_date_field) my_date_field) = 8 ORDER BY daytime DESC`

Comment: I have update the answer i hope without error this time